# Background repeat-x Messed Up On Tumblr Theme

Tags: html, css, tumblr

http://lt-chocolate.tumblr.com/

I just added header text with a background to my header tag and my background image on the top is very unstable. Is there anyway I can fix that?

Here's the css I have for the body and header right now.

```
html, body {

font-family: Georgia, "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
font-size: 12px;
color: #351F14;
background-color: #E6D0A1;
background-image: url('http://static.tumblr.com/pvgoybd/UEfmk0nj3/background_02.png');
background-repeat: repeat-x;

}
#masthead {
    max-width: 1400px;
    min-height: auto;
    position: relative;
    bottom: 8px;
    left: 82px;
}
#masthead h1 {
    font-family: Georgia, "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
    font-size: 48px;
    color: #F2EBD9;
    font-weight: bold;
    background-color: #4F3117;
    max-width: 401px;
    min-height: 62px;
    padding-left: 30px;
    margin-left: 30px;
    position: relative;
    bottom: 7px;
}
```

Is there anything I should work on to make it look better?

Comment: unstable how? Please elaborate.

Comment: put the image in the head?

Comment: why is it in the body, it doesnt make sense

Comment: you want something like this http://jsfiddle.net/btevfik/d9NuK/

Comment: You should really have separate divs for headings and things, as btevfik illustrated, body generally refers to all the viewable html code.

Answer (score 0):

You have set the background to both `html` and `body` so you see it twice.